# Unity script stops working after reactivate the gameobject where it is attached to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to make a ping pong animation but when it toggle the UI element the script stops working. Any idea? You may wonder why i don't use a animation instead, first it would be the same problem, second i need other script which are also attached to deactivated object :S

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UiFadingPingPong : MonoBehaviour{

    bool fadeTrigger = false;
    float currentVal = 0;
    public float duration = 10f;
    public bool enable = false;
    
    void Start(){
        currentVal = 0;
    }
    void OnEnable(){  
        enable = true;
    }
    void OnDisable(){  
        enable = false;
    }
        // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        if(enable){ 
            if(currentVal <= 0){
                fadeTrigger = false;
            }
            if(currentVal >= 1){
                fadeTrigger = true;
            }
            if(fadeTrigger == false){
                currentVal += Time.deltaTime / duration;    
            }else{
                currentVal -= Time.deltaTime / duration;    
            }
            Image image = GetComponent<Image>();
            var tempColor = image.color;
            tempColor.a = currentVal;
            image.color = tempColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By disabling the gameObject that this script is attached to, you're disabling the script as well.

This means that the `Update()` method will not run, and will not interpret that the `enable` variable is now set to `false`, (as `OnDisable()` is still executed, but after that no further processing will occur).

A solution to this would be to attach this script to a separate gameObject that isn't being enabled/disabled, and can manage this fading on/off effect

Comment: ok thanks for your reply :) Iguess that explain why the couroutine aproach doesn't work either. I thought that maybe there would be a workaroun.

Comment: Another solution would be like you mentioned using animation. Although I don't fully understand why it would be the same problem. 
The animation would include keyframes that set the alpha of the UI Element to either 255 to 0. The further apart the frames are, the slower the transition (or fade) between the two (or more) states will be, being opaque or transparent

Comment: Hey, it is the same problem because the Animation stops working when you have it attached to the object.

Comment: If you don't disable the gameObject that the Animator is attached to, it will work as expected. If you are setting `Time.timeScale`, and want the animation to continue when `Time.timeScale = 0` remember to set the `Update Mode` of the Animator to `Unscaled Time`

Comment: Hey thanks for you reply. Actually i figured out yesterday too that it was due to the timescale. Sorry for the missing information :) And yes Time.unscaledDeltaTime was what i needed. worked fine.